# How to call methods of an object that is created by loading shared object run time using dlopen

Tags: c++, dynamic, shared-objects

I created a test library called libmathClass.so which I will be loading from the code below. This shared object has a class and library call is created to return object of this class.
How can I call the methods of this object from the main code displayed below. I get undefined reference error from ld(linker) as it is not aware of the definition of methods.

```
void* handle;
handle=dlopen("math1/libmathClass.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(!handle)
{
    cout<<"error loading library: "<<dlerror()<<endl;
    exit(2);
}
else
{
    cout<<"***libmathClass.so library load successful!"<<endl;
}

void* (*mathInit) ();
mathInit = (void* (*)())dlsym(handle, "CreateMathOperationInstance");
if(!mathInit)
{
    cout<<"error loading instance method: "<<dlerror()<<endl;
    exit(3);
}
else
{
    cout<<"***method load successful!"<<endl;
}

mathOperationClass *mathInstance;
auto obj = (*mathInit)();
if(!obj)
{
    cout<<"object is not created"<<endl;
    exit(4);
}
else
{
    cout<<"object created!!!"<<endl;
    mathInstance = reinterpret_cast<mathOperationClass *>(obj);
}


int num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
int num2 = atoi(argv[2]);
cout<< mathInstance->AddInt(num1, num2)<<endl;
```

Command I used to compile - g++ --std=c++11 -g -o dynamicTest dynamicMain.cpp -ldl

Error message: 
dynamicMain.cpp:54: undefined reference to `mathOperationClass::AddInt(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: you need to link with the object that defines `AddInt()` of `mathInstance`

Comment: Did you export your function name `CreateMathOperationInstance` as `extern "C"`? If not you need to supply the mangled versions of the name (not recommended).

Comment: I did export CreateMathOperationInstance as extern "C" which just calls a static method mathOperationClass::CreateInstance () { return new mathOperationClass (); } and returns the pointer of object.

Comment: Just a quick update.  Its obvious that linker does not know definitions of methods called as they are loaded in run-time. The original intent of this question was to see if there is any other way to make this work(calling object methods defined in shared library). This particular solution works if the methods I am calling in the above program are defined as virtual methods which then will have its own vtable to play with and linker does not complain about undefined reference as they are sorted over runtime. virtual table a bliss for C++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mathInit = (void* (*)())dlsym(handle, "CreateMathOperationInstance");
```

Here you are using `dlsym()` to find this symbol in the shared library. This must be a function with `C` linkage, since the symbol name is not mangled. This is important, and keep this in mind, while you're staring at this line:

```
cout<< mathInstance->AddInt(num1, num2)<<endl;
```

Here, `AddInt` is a method of the class pointed to by `mathInstance`. A class method is just another function, except that it always takes a hidden `this` pointer as an extra argument. That's what a class method is, in so many words, and this actually turns out to be the case with a typical C++ implementation. C++ technically does not actually require this to be the case. A C++ implementation is free to implement methods in whatever manner produces the results that are compliant with the C++ specification. But, in practical terms, in a typical C++ implementation this is what a class method actually is. A function with an extra parameter that's referenced as `this`.

Therefore, in a manner of speaking, the above line is basically equivalent to:

```
cout<< mathOperationClass::AddInt(mathInstance, num1, num2)<<endl;
```

This basically is what's going on here, speaking very loosely.

This `mathOperationClass::AddInt` method/function is, presumably, in the same shared library that you `dlopen`-ed; and because you `dlopen`-ed it and you did not actually link to it, you have a reference to this symbol, and this reference cannot be resolved at runtime, hence your runtime undefined symbol error.

The only way you can even the slightest hope of invoking this class method -- if it can be invoked at all in this manner -- is by also using `dlsym()`. But in order to have even the slightest prayer of actually being be able to pull this off, a whole bunch of things need to happen just right.

First, you have to figure out the [actual mangled C++ symbol name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++). Using my Linux x86_64 g++ compiler as a reference, the mangled name for this method would be "_ZN18mathOperationClass6AddIntEii". With that in hand, you can use `dlsym` to find this symbol (or whatever your C++ implementation's actual mangled symbol name for this method is) in your shared library.

And once you have this symbol, what now? Well, let's hope that your C++ implementation does, indeed, have a hackable C++ ABI where you can invoke a class method by explicitly passing it an extra `this` parameter, something like this:

```
int (*addInt)(mathOperationClass *, int, int)=
    reinterpret_cast<int (*)(mathOperationClass *, int, int)>
        (dlsym(handle, "_ZN18mathOperationClass6AddIntEii"));

cout << (*addInt)(mathInstance, num1, num2) << endl;
```

This entire house of cards will collapse unless it can be confirmed that C++ methods can be invoked this hackish way, in your C++ implementation's ABI. Since you're already using `dlopen`() you're already in non-portable territory, using your C++ implementation-specific resources, so you might as well and figure out whether your C++ methods can be called this way. If not, you'll have to figure out how they can be called, using a plain pointer.

### And now for something completely different...

Having said all of the above:

There is one way you can likely avoid dealing with this mess: by making this class method a virtual class method. Virtual class methods are dispatched via an internal virtual function table. So, just try declaring this `AddInt` method as a virtual class method, and calling it, as is. It's very likely to work in your C++ implementation, since the compiler will not emit, in this instance, an explicit symbol reference for `mathOperationClass::AddInt`. It will find the method via the virtual function table that's quietly attached to every instance of the object.

Of course, you also need to keep in mind what virtual functions are, and the implications of them. But, in nearly all cases this is a pretty cheap way to call methods of classes that are dynamically loaded from a shared library.

Comment: `AddInt` is not a "normal pointer". It is a method call. And it is not invoked via the given pointer. This pointer is not a pointer to any function, but to an instance of a class. If you were to disassemble your compiled C++ code, you will discover that non-virtual method calls are equivalent to calls to external functions, using an external, mangled, symbol reference. That's how all modern C++ implementations work.

Comment: Except that this question is about code that is explicitly ***not*** linked to the shared library, but it is `dlopen`ed.

Comment: Ah yes. I was waiting for the 'cotcha' moment and this is it. My calls are going in the opposite direction (from the plugin to the shared library), but this situation is calling out to the plugin. Sorry, I am with you now.

Comment: AddInt is a regular public accessed method of class mathOperationClass. virtual method declaration seems like valid solution which I will try out. I actually tried linking the library during compilation and that worked fine. I have this issue only when dlopen'ing the shared library.

Comment: I upvoted for the suggestion to use virtual method which I did not think about. My methods were originally not virtual which is why linker was complaining about it. Thanks Sam Varshavchik for the suggestion, made me revisit my basics again.